# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, pca

[Example MATLAB Plot](http://s23.postimg.org/e5gp0fq1n/caca.png)

I am trying to implement Principal Component Analysis in MATLAB.

I have 5 vectors of raw data (A, B, C, D, E and F), each of which is represented as 1x291 vector.

I wrote a script to add different levels of noise to each vector, creating the variables A1, A2, A3, A4 and A5 and B1, B2, B3, B4 and B5 etc. These vectors are combined to create 5 matrices, which can be called matrices of noisy observations. Now for each material, I have a 5x291 observation matrix. Let's call them Ao, Bo, Co, Do, Eo and Fo.

I applied

```
[COEFFICIENTS, SCORE] = PCA(Ao)
```

to find the Score matrix. I then plotted this using

```
plot3(SCORE(:,1), SCORE(:,2), SCORE(:,3), '.');
```

for each Ao, Bo, Co, etc. Then I got this figure.

In terms of clustering, I was expecting that each 5 points (A1, A2, A3, A4, A5 and B1, B2, B3, B4 and B5 etc.) were closer to each other. But what I got is only a visualization of what the changes to the orginal data by the noise-addition script.

Now here is my question: What am I suppose to do in order to visualize

```
{A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6} 
{B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6}
{C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6} ...
```

as clusters in 3D?

(Now it looks like ({A1, B1, C1, D1, E1, F1}, {A2, B2, C2, D2, E2, F2} etc.)

Comment: This hurts my eyes. Can you make it a bit more readable?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you might need to run PCA on the transposed matrix.